# Google play games API error 12501 when signing in

Tags: java, android, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I was recently struck by google's convoluted API for game services and I need help :/

Whenever I try to sign into google play games services using `GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN`, I get error 12501 from signinResult.
my gso is written as:

```
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getResources().getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail().build();
```

If anyone has any idea about the error code and how to fix it, i'll really appreciate it :)
By the way, whenever I press on the signin button, it throws the error before even opening the login menu.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I use DEFAULT_SIGN_IN it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem:

When defining the app id in the manifest, instead of linking the value to strings.xml, I wrote it directly, and that somehow broke the program.

If anyone knows why I'd still love to hear!